# Three.js Shader to modify TextGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm completely new to three, hence this question which might be obvious to others.

So I achieved to load my font and build a TextGeometry accordingly. Additionally I created a kind of border using EdgesGeometry. This works fine.

But how do I achieve the geometries/mesh' to behave like this: https://edoardosmerilli.com/overview/ - In words: it kind of bends from left to center and vice versa (just like an old tube tv's screen) according to the scroll position. How do I achieve and effect like this? Is it a vertex shader? Is it three vectors that create this effect?

**I'm thankful for every hint!**

```
export default class Title {
    constructor($el, $scene) {
        this.scene = $scene;
        this.title = $el.firstElementChild;

        this.offset = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);

        const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        loader.load('/RL-Unno.json', (font) => {

            const geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(this.title.innerHTML, {
                font: font,
                size: 120,
                height: 1
            });
            geometry.center();
            this.init(geometry);
        })
    }

    init = (geometry) => {
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({opacity: 0});
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        this.getPosition();
        this.mesh.position.set(this.offset.x, this.offset.y, 0);
        this.scene.add(this.mesh);

        const geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
        const outline = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            linewidth: 4
        });
        this.border = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, outline);
        this.border.position.set(this.mesh.position.x, this.mesh.position.y, 0);
        this.scene.add(this.border);

        this.createListeners();
    };

    getPosition = () => {
        const {width, height, top, left} = this.title.getBoundingClientRect();

        this.offset.set(left - window.innerWidth / 2 + width / 2, -top + window.innerHeight / 2 - height / 2);
    };

    createListeners = () => {
        this.title.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            gsap.timeline().set(this.mesh.material, {
                opacity: 1
            })
        });

        this.title.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            gsap.timeline().set(this.mesh.material, {
                opacity: 0
            })
        });
    };

    update = () => {
        if (!this.mesh) return;
        this.getPosition();

        gsap.timeline().set([this.mesh.position, this.border.position], {
            x: this.offset.x,
            y: this.offset.y,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also asked at the `three.js` forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/shader-to-modify-textgeometry/14738

Comment: @Mugen87 Didn't know which one's the better forum to address this question ;)